# angular4 async template binding don't unsubscribe with zip

Tags: angular, rxjs, polling

I have an async template binding such as:

```ts
[binding]="polling$ | async"
```

In my code, `polling$` is derived from a bunch of initial promise like observables combined into a single `zipObs$` for convenience:

```ts
let a$: AsyncSubject<any>, b$: AsyncSubject<any>;
// ... init a$ and b$
let zipObs$ = Observable.zip(a$, b$);
```

Up to this point everything is fine. That's what the polling logic looks like (not so sure about this..):

```ts
function poll() {
    let current$ = getSomeObservable();
    let next$ = current.delay(5000).concatMap(poll);
    return Observable.merge(current$, next$);
}
this.polling$ = zipObs$.concatMap(poll);
```

It kind of works as expected, the only problem being that the polling doesn't stop when the component is destroyed, i.e angular doesn't seem able to automatically unsubscribe all the observables. I managed to work around that issue by tracking the `Observable.zip` subscription and manually unsubscribing on destroy:

```ts
private _sub: Subscripton;
// ... constructor or ngOnInit
let a$: AsyncSubject<any>, b$: AsyncSubject<any>;
// ... init a$ and b$
let zipObs$ = Observable.create(obs => {
    this._sub = Observable.zip(a$, b$).subscribe([a,b] => obs.next([a,b]))
});
// ...
ngOnDestroy() { this._sub.unsubscribe(); }
```

Now it stops polling when the component is destroyed but I can't figure what is stopping angular from doing that all by itself. I suspect it is because of the static operator but I'm not sure. Can you tell me why this is?

We're still using angular 4.4.4

*EDIT*: couldn't reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/q6xwzhbk/ :thinkingface:

Comment: If you subscribe to `polling$` somewhere in your component you need to unsubscribe yourself. Angular can't know made a subscription somewhere in your code. You don't need to worry about `async` because this gets unsubscribe automatically when the pipe is destroyed.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in a demoable way - for example via https://stackblitz.com/? It would very surprising indeed if the problem were with `| async`, much more likely it is due to what @martin wrote above.

Comment: @martin there are no calls to `.subscribe` anywhere else in the code than the workaround aforementioned

Comment: @arturgrzesiak see added a fiddle, although I couldn't reproduce

Comment: I'm starting to suspect it could be to do with unmanaged subscriptions from within a child component

Comment: I had a similar issue. It turned out that i was dynamically creating a duplicate component using ViewContainerRef and ComponentFactoryResolver. I hope this helps.